# Is there any way to disable the red notification badge in macOS Terminal?

Tags: mac, terminal.app

As of OS X 10.7 (I think?) Terminal.app will show a red badge counting the number of bells the encountered while the terminal is in the background.

Is it possible to dissable this badge?

Comment: Here's your cross site duplicate: [Is there a way to suppress badge counts and the dock icon bounce for Terminal.app in Lion?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18605/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-badge-counts-and-the-dock-icon-bounce-for-terminal-ap)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to disable it with:

```
user=$( scutil <<< "show State:/Users/ConsoleUser" | awk '/Name :/ && ! /loginwindow/ { print $3 }' )

sudo -u $user defaults write com.apple.systempreferences AttentionPrefBundleIDs 0
```

Comment: Can you add some commentary about what this command does? It looks like the first line basically extracts the username and then the second makes the setting change. Does the change require logging out/back in or restarting to take effect?